# How to split different date format in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have some dates like this :

- 15 Décembre 2012
- Du mardi 18 avril au jeudi 25 mai
- Le 25, 26 et 27 Juin

Just examples in French.

My database looks like :

```
 CREATE TABLE DateTest(id_date int(11), date text, date_deb date, date_fin date);
```

I would like to insert my different dates regardless format of them.
I can easily insert the first example, the second too, but concerning the first, I don't know..

It can have few separators (, or et), and when I get the number of the day (25 for the first), I don't have the month.

Comment: What is the code used to attempt the insertion?

Comment: You may have to catch all numbers with 2 digits for days, and catch month manually (with a list of valid months : `Janvier`,`Février` etc... if you are sure of the writing... if a user can write `fevrier`, you will have to make it non-case-sensitive, and add `Fevrier` too (without accent)...

Comment: Have you heard of PHP `DateTime::createFromDateString`? http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.createfromdatestring.php

Comment: @marekful I'm using PDO, with prepared statement and execute query. I use $statement->bindValue(1,$date). I can pastebin the full code if you prefer :)
@Random You think I should put the numbers in an array, and save the month in a variable ? I though to it, maybe could work, but very binding if there are few months. I don't have to use month with and without accent, they're all without, and I use `strtolower` on the whole date

Comment: @marekful I didn't, but seems to be an old PHP function. I'm using 5.5 or 5.6, but your function stop at 5.3 ?

Comment: Sorry, I meant http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Comment: it seems to be the same no ? (PHP 5 >= 5.3.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do, is write several regular expressions for catching the different ways that these date periods can be entered. For the third format, for example:

```
$month_nrs = array('janvier' => 1, 'février' => 2, 'mars' => 3, 'avril' => 4, 'mai' => 5, 'juin' => 6, 'juillet' => 7, 'août' => 8, 'septembre' => 9, 'octobre' => 10, 'novembre' => 11, 'décembre' => 12);

$period = 'Le 25, 26 et 27 Juin';
//$period = 'Le 25 et 26 Juin';
//$period = 'Le 25, 26, 27 et 28 Juin';
if (preg_match('/(\d{1,2})(?:,\s*\d{1,2})* et (\d{1,2})\s+(janvier|février|mars|avril|mai|juin|juillet|août|septembre|octobre|novembre|décembre)/i', $period, $matches)) {
    $month_name = strtolower($matches[3]);
    $month_nr = $month_nrs[$month_name];
    $day_deb = $matches[1];
    $day_fin = $matches[2];
    $date_deb = date('Y').'-'.$month_nr.'-'.$day_deb;
    $date_fin = date('Y').'-'.$month_nr.'-'.$day_fin;

    echo "Date deb: $date_deb, date fin: $date_fin";
}
```

Comment: I cannot evaluate your answer, because I'm very bad in regex :/ Could you explain me a little bit the preg_match() content ? I though to regular expression to solve my problem, but I don't really know how to use them :/

Comment: This regular expression looks for a pattern of a date period entered as a list of consecutive days in a month (see the three examples in the `$period` variable). It then picks out the first and last numbers, and the name of the month, which go into the `$matches` variable. However, if you have difficulty writing regular expressions, this is probably not a way to go.

Comment: I think your solution could be fine, so I will try to understand yours, and make mine for my project :)